# For only one PC accessToken not saving on cookies while refreshToken save - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, cookies, token

I have a system made on vueJs. When I do login it saves accessToken and refresh token in browser cookies. It works fine in all computer and network. But specific in one PC it saves only refresh token and avoiding to save accessT[image]oken. I have no idea what can I do.

Comment: I suspect that this is a browser-settings thing. If your user decides not to save cookies at all, the browser will not save cookies. You can check the settings in that browser, or try a different browser on that machine.

Comment: I already tried 3 more browser. firefox, edge, chromium. I got same error. one more thing if cookies not enable refresh token will not save also

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a browser-settings thing. If your user decides not to save cookies at all, the browser will not save cookies. You can check the settings in that browser, or try a different browser on that machine.

What you usually need to check is not different pc's, but different browsers on one pc.

If you want to be thorough, try safari on mac & firefox and chrome on windows.

Depending on your audience, you may also still need to check internet explorer, but this is getting less and less common.